# Adobe Flex iOS application ipa too large when deployed

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder, ipa

I am developing an Adobe Flex app for web, desktop, Android and iOS.
When I package the ipa for iOS, the size is 31Mb. After deployment, the size becomes 106Mb which is refused by Apple for publication.
When I unzip the ipa, the size of my SWF is 3.5Mb, all the other files' size is 2.5Mb but `<my app name>` file is 95Mb.

I am using Flash Builder 4.7 to do the packaging.

Do you have any idea, why this is the case and how to reduce this size?

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the app size by removing unused code and images. Now I am just under the limit.